# Can I fetch exact 'Get Tickets' uri from facebook event, which is after all redirections

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I want to obtain exact "get Tickets" uri from facebook, in php. For e.g. facebook event is

1. https://www.facebook.com/events/703571536339301/,
   and "Get Ticket" uri for above event is
2. https://www.facebook.com/ajax/events/ticket.php?event_id=703571536339301&source=1. If I paste this in browser with valid fb session, it works and take me to after some redirections
3. https://tickets.axs.com/eventShopperV3UK.html?wr=5c6faf43-a25f-4bae-880f-a33ff124266e&preFill=1&eventid=240417&src=AEGAXS1_WMAIN&skin=theo2&fbShareURL=www.axs.com%2Fevents%2F240417%2Fstereophonics-tickets%3F%26ref%3Devs_fb
   **Which is expected.**

**Problem:** I'm not able to fetch url no 3, above from url 2 in server side PHP or commandline. Is this possible or it only works through browser ?

I've also tried : curl -L (didn't work).

Any help ?

Comment: if you try command line using curl, you may need cookies.txt and use cookie-jar as well. If 2nd url as you quote is working with active session, then similar session for login you have to maintain and pass as cookies for fetching url with curl -k option and mentioning cookies and cookies-jar options in curl.